# Select values from two lists of dictionaries in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I am writing a playbook to configure Cisco ASA and trying to figure out a way to form route commands based on values from these two lists of dictionaries:

```yaml
dict1:
- name: Interface_LAN
  vrf: LAN
  gw: 10.10.10.1
  vlan: 10
- name: Interface_DMZ
  vrf: DMZ
  gw: 10.20.20.1
  vlan: 20
dict2:
- name: LAN
  vrf: LAN
  subnet: 192.168.100.0
- name: LAN2
  vrf: LAN
  subnet: 192.168.200.0
- name: DMZ
  vrf: DMZ
  subnet: 192.168.300.0
```

The item selection per command would be based on the VRF attribute.

The commands I need to construct:

```
route Interface_LAN 192.168.100.0 255.255.255.0 10.10.10.1 1
route Interface_LAN 192.168.200.0 255.255.255.0 10.10.10.1 1
route Interface_DMZ 192.168.300.0 255.255.255.0 10.20.20.1 1
```

Could someone suggest a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the filter [`selectattr`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.selectattr) in order to select the interface matching the VRF from the other list.

You task would then be:

```yaml
- command: >-
    route {{ vrf.name }} {{ item.subnet }} 255.255.255.0 {{ vrf.gw }} 1
  loop: "{{ dict2 }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.subnet }}"
  vars:
    vrf: "{{ dict1 | selectattr('vrf', '==', item.vrf) | first }}"
```

---

As a demonstration, given the task:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "route {{ vrf.name }} {{ item.subnet }} 255.255.255.0 {{ vrf.gw }} 1"
  loop: "{{ dict2 }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.subnet }}"
  vars:
    vrf: "{{ dict1 | selectattr('vrf', '==', item.vrf) | first }}"
    dict1:
      - name: Interface_LAN
        vrf: LAN
        gw: 10.10.10.1
        vlan: 10
      - name: Interface_DMZ
        vrf: DMZ
        gw: 10.20.20.1
        vlan: 20
    dict2:
      - name: LAN
        vrf: LAN
        subnet: 192.168.100.0
      - name: LAN2
        vrf: LAN
        subnet: 192.168.200.0
      - name: DMZ
        vrf: DMZ
        subnet: 192.168.300.0
```

This yields:

```
ok: [localhost] => (item=192.168.100.0) => 
  msg: route Interface_LAN 192.168.100.0 255.255.255.0 10.10.10.1 1
ok: [localhost] => (item=192.168.200.0) => 
  msg: route Interface_LAN 192.168.200.0 255.255.255.0 10.10.10.1 1
ok: [localhost] => (item=192.168.300.0) => 
  msg: route Interface_DMZ 192.168.300.0 255.255.255.0 10.20.20.1 1
```

Comment: This works exactly as described, thank you so much!!!